# limit number of characters in a string - XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xpath, limit, character

I am using a third party asp.net control to pull and display the latest content from the database. The control pulls the title of the latest published content using a xsl file. My issue is the title(content piece) being too long. They place I used to display has no room for about 100 characters. I need to trim(not the white spaces) end part and may be limit it to a few words or some characters. It uses the xsl file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <xsl:for-each select="Collection/Content">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="Type ='Assets' or Type = 8 ">
                                        javascript:void window.open('showcontent.aspx?id=<xsl:value-of select="ID"/>')
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="QuickLink"/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

This part, `<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>` is where you the title is and I need to shorten it.. (putting ... in the end perhaps)

How can I do it? Can I get this done in the xsl file itself without using JQuery? Many thanks,

Comment: Correction: This part,* = This part,<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>, putt* = putting

Comment: add corrections to the question by editing the question; don't just comment about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802374/how-to-limit-string-word-count-in-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 7):

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(Title) > 100">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(Title, 1, 97)" />...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="Title" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Why `97`? This just makes the example more confusing.

Comment: @Rudey The OP seemed to be saying he had room to display about 100 characters. Taking the first 97 characters of the title leaves room for the 3 dots `...` shown in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `substring(text, startingIndex, length)` XSLT function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(Title, 1, 100)"/>
```

Note that substring index starts from 1, instead of the usual 0.

More at http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xpathFunctionIndex.html

Note also, that .NET does not implements XSLT 2.0, only XSLT 1.0 (hence the above reference: its the list of XSLT 1.0 functions).

Comment: @Chris: Because the OP apparently never came back after asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Limit the 20 characters

If your code likes this

```
<xsl:value-of select="EmpBio" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Just change with new one written below

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(BioData, 1, 20)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Note that the quotation marks are removed from the element name BioData